# redux saga before action

Tags: redux, redux-saga

I have whole application depending on config data that are loaded with request from server, how can I create blocking "before" action on every action using redux saga, now my globalSaga looks like this. The help would be really appreciated

```
function * rootSaga () {
  yield takeLatest(LOAD_ONBOARDING.REQUEST,loadOnboardingSaga)
  const res = yield put.resolve(loadOnboarding())
  yield console.log(res)

  yield all([
    fork(globalSaga),
    fork(spaceSaga),
    fork(profileSaga),
    fork(userSaga),
    fork(pagesSaga)
  ])
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`takeLatest` is the same as forking with automatic cancellation of each subsequent fork. Check [this](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/recipes/#debouncing) for a descriptive example.

So in your case since `loadOnboardingSaga` should continuously block next calls the cheapest solution would be to put it all under `loadOnboardinSaga` since there is a direct succession like this:

```js
function* initRestSaga() {
  yield all([
    fork(globalSaga),
    fork(spaceSaga),
    fork(profileSaga),
    fork(userSaga),
    fork(pagesSaga)
  ])
}

function* loadOnboardingSaga() {
  //...
  const res = yield put.resolve(loadOnboarding())
  yield console.log(res)
  yield call(initRestSaga)

}

function* rootSaga() {
  yield takeLatest(LOAD_ONBOARDING.REQUEST, loadOnboardingSaga)
}
```

Otherwise you have to manually fork and cancel each and every side effect in between takeLatest and last fork.

Comment: thank you very much, this is possible solution I didn't see. Finally decided to chain blocking actions inside each saga. I am not so satisfied with this architectural choice, but did't find any elegant solution for this problem, how to chain sagas containing async requests synchronously. Maybe I should start a thread with this question

Comment: If you find the answer useful you can accept it or upvote. Happy to help.